# Classic ASP interact with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have run into a bit of a problem that i cant seem to work around in my head.

I have an asp page that has a while loop to print dynamic data coming from the database, in particular, checkboxes like so;

```
// form open up here
<% do while not rs.EOF %>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-id="<%=rs.Fields("this_id")">
<%
    rs.movenext()
loop
%>
// form end down here
```

Down the bottom of the page i have a bit of jQuery like so;

```
$('#removestuff').click(function(e) {

    $("#thisform").submit(function(e) {

        var url = "functions.asp";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#thisform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I have this as i have several buttons that do several different things.

Im having 2 problems;

1. The id from the 'data-id' attribute isnt coming through.
2. I have no idea how to 'deserialize' and deal with the data on the classic asp side.

All i simply want to do is `Response.Write` each 'id'

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: 1) Isn't coming through... where? 2) It's a querystring, so in this case you can use `Request.Form()` to retrieve it. You don't need to do any deserialisation

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the response ... When i console.log the serialize line, all i am seeing is checkbox=on instead of the id thats being written in the data-id attribute

Comment: That's because `data` attributes are not sent in form data. If you need those too you would need to include them in hidden fields in the form HTML

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you